# Query Performance Reduces When i use much indexing in the mysql table structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table that contain 10 million records and this record updated weekly may be it get reduced or may get increased .

And over this records I will have to perform select query with different where clause and this perform very slow.

What is was thinking that update and delete query has to perform lot's of effort for updating and deleting the indexes for each column.

so for that I have truncate the table and insert the record again . but it takes the same time so any one can provide me the suggestion for executing the query smoothly .

I have a very simple query but it takes too much time (i am using joomla with mysql)

```
SELECT *
FROM all_data
WHERE `stock` != 'Out of stock'
   AND `sitename` = 'something.com'
   AND `auction_time` = ''
   AND `type` != 'Accessories'
GROUP BY `offer_new_name`
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This link may be useful http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-tuning.html

Comment: how have you profiled the execution? what is the query plan? and why are you having a table "all_data" with 10M rows without (apparently) any optimization of data... this all sounds very fishy.

Comment: also, your question title doesn't seem to match the question content. you don't even mention your indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, using string comparisons in conditionals is bad.

You should use codes like

```
Out of Stock | 1
```

That way you can say: `WHERE stock != 1` that will save a string comparison. That same goes for the type field. That will save a fair bit of time. If you only have 3 or 4 different statuses or types its generally a good idea to do a "lookup table" then you can query them much faster.

Group By will also be slowing it down. There is only so much you can do with a query, but ultimately you need good DB design to make this stuff go faster.

Comment: it improves up to some extend.